# How to wait for the completion of two async functions that should run parallel

Tags: c#, async-await

If i got the following snippet:

```
async Task MyFunc()
{
    await DoWork1();
    await DoWork2();
}
async Task<object> DoWork1() { /*Do work here*/ }
async Task<object> DoWork2() { /*Do other work here*/ }

void main()
{
    MyTask();
    //Do some stuff which needs MyFunc() to be completed beforehand.
}
```

What i am trying to do is to let DoWork1() and DoWork2() run parallel BUT only return to main() if they are both completed.

Would it work like that? or is there a better solution?

Comment: It does **not** work as excpeted. I do it always the same way - but I need the tasks run synchronously. Since you want them to run in parallel do it in the way Grumbler85 provided.

Comment: But await will not move to the next await until it is ready, or am i wrong here?

Comment: This SO question will give you an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974635/multiple-parallel-async-calls-with-await-in-async-ctp

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that, and i searched for a while :)

Comment: Yeah, the first await gets called when the first task is ready. If the second task is ready the second await is immediately called or after the second task is ready.

Comment: So they run parallel, but the results are "returned"/assigned in the "right" order?

Comment: @dasheddot I think you have asynchronous in a step by step form - so if the main thread has nothing to do, there won't be any benefit.

Comment: Yep. You are right. Since he is starting the second task just after the first task is finished. This is exactly the behaviour I want in my projects since the main thread is GUI and the tasks need to be run in the specific order (not parallel). Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WhenAll` for simple parallelism:

```
async Task MyFunc()
{
  var task1 = DoWork1();
  var task2 = DoWork2();
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```