# async but not parallel

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a contract that defines an asynchronous operation, but I'm calling it from an area that isn't set up as async.  I want to make multiple calls in parallel, so I started with this:

```
var tasks = inputs.Select(input => service.GetResult(input));
var results = tasks.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
```

I figured that would start all the calls in parallel and then wait on the second line.  However, looking at the logging of the target service, I found that the calls were coming in serially.

I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/) that shows a similar method of calling to mine and explains that it won't necessarily run in parallel, so I just switched it to a straight parallel call to test:

```
var results = new ConcurrentBag<Result>();
Parallel.ForEach(inputs, input => results.Add(service.GetResult(input).Result));
```

This works as expected - I can see that the calls are coming to the service in parallel.

So, this brings me to two questions:

1)  What are the downsides of going with Option 2?
2)  How would I get Option 1 to work correctly?

Here are a couple services to replicate the issue.  Call ClientService with WCFTestClient and a list of four ints (1, 2, 3, 4) as an example.  (Port will probably need to change when you run it.)

TargetService:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncNotParallel
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class TargetService : ITargetService
    {
        public async Task<int> GetResult(int input)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"In:  {input}");
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Do stuff.
            Trace.WriteLine($"Out: {input}");
            return input;
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITargetService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<int> GetResult(int input);
    }
}
```

ClientService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncNotParallel
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class ClientService : IClientService
    {
        public int GetResults(List<int> inputs)
        {
            // Option 1:
            var tasks = inputs.Select(input => Execute((ITargetService service) => service.GetResult(input)));
            var results1 = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.Sum();

            // Option 2:
            var bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Parallel.ForEach(inputs, input => bag.Add(Execute((ITargetService service) => service.GetResult(input)).Result));
            var results2 = bag.Sum();

            return results1 + results2;
        }

        private TResult Execute<TService, TResult>(Func<TService, TResult> operation)
        {
            var address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:34801/TargetService.svc");
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<TService>(binding, address);
            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = operation(channel);
            ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
            return result;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IClientService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetResults(List<int> inputs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use .Result, always await async calls.

Comment: @Bart:  In order to "never use .Result," I would need to change the entire client to be async/await, but this is the only location that I've got an async contract.  I can make my own local copy of the contract (that is in a shared DLL) and just go with the Parallel call, but that doesn't answer my question nor help me understand what is happening here.

Comment: asycn is not the same thing as parallel.  Asycn is about not blocking a thread while IO is occurring while parallel is about running on multiple threads.  There is some overlap in that you can asynchronously wait on another thread to finish, but the main purpose of async is to keep threads from becoming unnecessarily blocked.

Comment: @juharr:  That's true.  But, I was also under the impression that starting several async calls before blocking your current thread to wait for completion would effectively make the calls be parallel.  Are you saying that's incorrect?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674880.aspx) are some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343081/run-two-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-collect-results-in-net-4-5) that I think [agree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974635/multiple-parallel-async-calls-with-await) with my assessment above.

Comment: @zimdanen Yes, because by default it will try to use the same context or thread to complete the code after any awaits that may exist in your `GetResult` method.

Comment: @juharr:  So, the links I provided are all explicitly wrong?  None of that will run in parallel because none of them explicitly tell the calls to disregard the context when they return (though use of `ConfigureAwait`, for instance)?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know for sure, but it seems to me that the posted answer likely includes correct inferences (based on the tags in your question) about what `service` is and the environment you're executing the code. Changing the concurrency mode should address your primary concern. If you want more specific help, you need to provide a better question.

Comment: Provide a good MCVE in your target environment. This sample will deadlock in WPF/WinForms but run parallel in ie a Console. You can subsitute the service call with Task.Delay.

Comment: @PeterDuniho:  I've just added an MCVE that shows what I'm experiencing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:  I've just added an MVCE that shows what I'm experiencing.

Comment: OK, so the client is WCF too. I'm not sure about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ConcurrencyMode` of your service is `Single` (the default - can be overridden in a `ServiceBehavior` attribute), it means the *service handles calls sequentially*. So both options really execute sequentially, it's just that the second one got unordered results. You can switch to `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, which is more dangerous since it means the service has to be carefully authored to be thread-safe.

1. `Parallel` is optimized for CPU-bound operations and will parellelize your calls according to the number of cores in your system. In effect, you can parallelize IO-bound operations more than that, so the entire thing would execute slower. In addition, you're using `.Result` on every thread, wasting wait time in each task `Parallel` spawns. I would not use this approach. Lastly, `ConcurrentBag` is unordered, which may or not be important to you.
2. In the first option, you're launching each WCF call from the UI thread - sequentially. This will most likely cause the calls to be handled by the `ConcurrencyMode.Single` service in the same order of the list.

You should probably be using `Task.WaitAll()` instead of `Task.WhenAll().Result`. I would **highly discourage** you from doing that on a UI thread though. This is the root cause for many nasty UI hangs. You can simply launch an async method from a synchronous method (without `Wait()`ing for it) - just fire and forget. After awaiting the tasks, just update the UI as needed in the async method.

One last recommendation - before making multiple concurrent calls using the same channel, you should `Open()` it for better performance. Even though channels do that automatically, there's a benefit here due to some locking the channel does.

EDIT -

After seeing your updated code, the problem is that you're launching a task and then waiting for the channel to close synchronously (which blocks until the call finishes). Here's a better implementation:

```
private async Task<TResult> Execute<TService, TResult>(Func<TService, Task<TResult>> operation)
{
    var address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:34801/A");
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    var channel = ChannelFactory<TService>.CreateChannel(binding, address);
    var clientChannel = (IClientChannel)channel;
    try
    {
        var result = await operation(channel).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (clientChannel.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            await Task.Factory.FromAsync(clientChannel.BeginClose, clientChannel.EndClose, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else if (clientChannel.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        {
            clientChannel.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also modified it to use the cached `ChannelFactory`, and to properly closing and aborting the channel.

Comment: A few points of clarification:  The target service is `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`/`ConcurrenceMode.Single`.  The caller is also not a GUI but a different service (with the same options).  The service client is built using ChannelFactory and automatically wraps with open/close calls.  Onto my question:   It sounds like you're suggesting just switching out the `WhenAll` for `WaitAll` and then getting the results from the tasks separately after?  That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Each call creates a new channel and opens it explicitly before making the actual service call, so the channels aren't shared.  Changing `ConcurrencyMode` didn't make a difference.  Also, the service definitely isn't handling them sequentially in Option 2, because I can see the in logs that I've got multiple calls going at the same time, and the time for the caller to complete is significantly less as well.

Comment: That's fair enough.  I will try to put together an mcve.

Comment: Okay, I've added an MCVE.  I was incorrect that it explicitly opens, but explicitly opening didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks; the edit answers the MCVE.  I'll post a new, slightly-more-complicated question with MCVE and link to this one tomorrow if I can't get the solution into the actual code.